# Set Slim container within middleware

Tags: php, slim

How do I set something in Slim's container within middleware?  Below is what I tried.

```
$app = new \Slim\App(); // Using Slim 3.0

$app->add(function ($request, $response, $next) {
    $this->logger->addInfo('$this'.print_r($this,1));  //This works, so I can access the container
    $this->app->getContainer()['xxx']='yyy';
    $next->getContainer()['foo']='bar';
    $this->bla=123;
    $this->logger->addInfo('$this'.print_r($this,1));
    $response = $next($request, $response);
    return $response;
});

$container = $app->getContainer();

$container['logger'] = function() {
    $logger = new \Monolog\Logger('my_logger');
    $file_handler = new \Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler("../logs/app.log");
    $logger->pushHandler($file_handler);
    return $logger;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$this->app->getContainer()['xxx']='yyy';
```

Should be

```
$this['xxx'] = 'yyy';
```

as the container is bound to the callable.

Comment: Thank you geggleto.  Yea, after more playing, I expected so, and that `$this->bla=123;` would also work.  I was doing things the "wrong" way previously which made it not so apparent.